# VB Code For Showing Battery Status

Tags: vb.net

I Have Use This Code For Displaying Battery Status In VB 6.0 . But Showing 'Syntax Error' What Should I Import And How ?

```
Dim power As PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus
Dim percent As Single = power.BatteryLifePercent
MsgBox ("Percent battery life remaining: " & percent * 100)
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure that is *not* VB6 code

Comment: I think OP wants the same code in VB6. He has provided the code for VB.NET and he wants the same in VB6

Comment: @Ruhal- how do you know that?

Comment: I now think he is trying to get VB.NET code to run in VB6.  One thing is certain - the OP lacks clarity

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables:- Sir He has written *I Have Use This Code For Displaying Battery Status In VB 6.0* and the below code is in VB.Net. Thats why I guessed that! ;)

Comment: It is a total mish-mash: `What Should I Import` then implies .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for VB6 code(which I guessed) Then I found the code [here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=8682):-

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    MsgBox "Battery status: " & getBatteryStatus(), vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Battery Status"
    End
End Sub

Public Function getBatteryStatus() As Integer
  Dim obj As Object, obj2 As Object, stat As Integer
'  Get Battery Status
'  Return Value Meaning
'0 No battery
'1 The battery is discharging.
'2 The system has access to AC so no battery is being discharged. However, the battery is not necessarily charging.
'3 Fully Charged
'4 Low
'5 Critical
'6 Charging
'7 Charging and High
'8 Charging and Low
'9 Charging and Critical
'10 Undefined
'11 Partially Charged
  stat = 0
  Set obj = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Battery")
  For Each obj2 In obj 'loop in objects
    stat = obj2.BatteryStatus
  Next
  getBatteryStatus = stat
End Function
```

In VB.NET you can try like this:-

```
'Assembly: System.Windows.Forms.dll
'Namespace: System
'Namespace: Microsoft.VisualBasic
'Namespace: System.Windows.Forms

Dim power As PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus
Dim percent As Single = power.BatteryLifePercent
MsgBox("Percent battery life remaining: " & percent * 100)
```

Comment: Instead Of Showing 1,2./....can it show direct % e.g. 33% left

Comment: @DivyamSolanki:- It would be great if you can specify that in which language you want the code. VB6 or VB.Net. Also update the same in your original question!

Comment: i want in vb6 and vb.net both

Comment: @DivyamSolanki:- I have provided the solution for both VB.NET and VB6. Also please edit your question with the same! Hope that  helps:)